# The database is not being updated

Tags: python, sql, mysql

Code

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect(
            host=HOSTNAME,
            user=USERNAME,
            passwd=PASSWORD,
            database=DATABASE
        )
        crsr = conn.cursor()
        upp1 = f"UPDATE `ord` SET `Status` = '{newstatus}' WHERE `ord`.`telgramname` = {tgname}"

        crsr.execute(upp1)
        conn.commit()
        crsr.close()
        conn.close()
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Статус обнавлен')
```

When I send the data to be exposed, no error occurs, but the data in the Status column is not updated in the database

I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

You should switch to prepared statements, so that you can avoid sql injection.

of course you should check is the values are actually set

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect(
            host=HOSTNAME,
            user=USERNAME,
            passwd=PASSWORD,
            database=DATABASE
        )
cursor = cnx.cursor(prepared=True)
stmt = "UPDATE `ord` SET `Status` = %s WHERE `ord`.`telgramname` = %s"        
cursor.execute(stmt, (newstatus,tgname))
```